# Install GD Failure

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I would like to install the modules required to run Circos. One of the required modules is `GD`.

- *OS: Mac OS X Version 10.7.4
- Installed libgd: `brew install libgd`*

Following `cpan[1]> install GD`

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/GD.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 12 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  10
Files=2, Tests=13,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.11 cusr  0.02 csys =  0.15 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 1/13 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  LDS/GD-2.46.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports LDS/GD-2.46.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 LDS/GD-2.46.tar.gz                           : make_test NO
```

Any ideas as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this particular module, passing the unit tests is pretty [hit-or-miss](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=GD%202.46;os=darwin;reports=1). If you're comfortable with this single test failure (which is about [writing jpeg files](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/GD-2.46/t/GD.t)), then just force an install.

```
cpan[1]> force install GD
```

or

```
$ cpan -f GD
```

Since the test failure is a jpeg issue, you might want to see if you have libjpeg and its friends installed properly.

Comment: I think the general reason for the failure is because the version of libjpeg has been upgraded to 8, and the test file is written with 62, which causes a difference in the written data/metadata